# Detecting a % Change

Tags: java, math

Hello so im making a loading bar so my loading bar should be 246px so I worked out how many PX it should move per % and that answer was 2.46 Px now my issue is how do i detect the % change so at the moment i have this

```
if(Math.round(sumCount / size * 100.0) == 1) {
                        LoadingBar.setLocation((int)-243.54,280);
                    } else if(Math.round(sumCount / size * 100.0) == 2) {
                         LoadingBar.setLocation((int)-241.08,280);
                    } else if(Math.round(sumCount / size * 100.0) == 3) {
                         LoadingBar.setLocation((int)-238.62,280);
                    } else if(Math.round(sumCount / size * 100.0) == 4) {
                         LoadingBar.setLocation((int)-236.16,280);
                    } else if(Math.round(sumCount / size * 100.0) == 5) {
                         LoadingBar.setLocation((int)-233.7,280);
                    } else if(Math.round(sumCount / size * 100.0) == 6) {
                         LoadingBar.setLocation((int)-231.24,280);
                    } else if(Math.round(sumCount / size * 100.0) == 7) {
                         LoadingBar.setLocation((int)-228.78,280);
                    }
```

And I really dont want to do this as it will take ages and its a way to do it i was wondering if anyone could think or show me a better way to do this so

```
Math.round(sumCount / size * 100.0)
```

Is the % it downloded and -246 is where the loading bar is drawn just off the screen

Comment: Does this work? `sumCount / size` looks suspiciously like integer division. And if it's not, you don't need the decimal in `100`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you writing `(int)-243.54` etc instead of just `-243`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop or piece of code, that triggers the loading bar change, just add this:

```
LoadingBar.setLocation((int)(246-2.46*Math.round(sumCount / size * 100.0)));
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: This has worked but loaded in from the left not right

Comment: Mb lol my maths is bad sometimes yes it has worked thank you very much

Comment: Np. Mark as best answer then, please. Thx!!